# How do I test an error on reading from a request body?

Tags: unit-testing, http, go, error-handling

I'm writing unit tests for http Handlers in golang. When looking at code coverage reports of this I am running into the following issue: When reading the request body from a request, `ioutil.ReadAll` might return an error that I need to handle. Yet, when I write unit tests for my handler I do not know  how to send a request to my handler in a way that it will trigger such an error (premature end of content seems not to generate such an error but will generate an error on unmarshaling the body). This is what I am trying to do:

```
package demo

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func HandlePostRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, bytesErr := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if bytesErr != nil {
        // intricate logic goes here, how can i test it?
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    // continue...
}

func TestHandlePostRequest(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(HandlePostRequest))
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("testdata/fixture.json")
    res, err := http.Post(ts.URL, "application/json", bytes.NewReader(data))
    // continue...
}
```

How can I write a test case for `HandlePostRequest` that also covers the case of `bytesErr` not being `nil`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You may create and use an [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) forged by you, which deliberately returns an error when reading its body. You don't necessarily need a whole new request, a faulty body is enough (which is an [`io.ReadCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser)).

Simplest achieved by using the [`httptest.NewRequest()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewRequest) function where you can pass an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) value which will be used (wrapped to be an `io.ReadCloser`) as the request body.

Here's an example `io.Reader` which deliberately returns an error when attempting to read from it:

```
type errReader int

func (errReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return 0, errors.New("test error")
}
```

Example that will cover your error case:

```
func HandlePostRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading the body: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("No error, body: %s\n", body)
}

func main() {
    testRequest := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/something", errReader(0))
    HandlePostRequest(nil, testRequest)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i0Rd9Z6rnE)):

```
Error reading the body: test error
```

See related question if you would need to simulate error reading from a response body (not from a request body): [How to force error on reading response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171123/how-to-force-error-on-reading-response-body/53173459#53173459)

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for. The return statement is there in my real code, but thanks for stating it anyways, I'll add it to the question to avoid confusion for others.

Answer (score 1):

I did extract the code that reads the body and processes the response and then used the following approach to create a response that would fail when reading the body:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type BrokenReader struct{}

func (br *BrokenReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("failed reading")
}

func (br *BrokenReader) Close() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed closing")
}

func main() {
    headers := http.Header{
        "Content-Length": {"1"},
    }
    reader := BrokenReader{}

    resp := http.Response{
        Body:   &reader,
        Header: headers,
    }

    _, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_R9hI2AWm9G