# Mock ioUtils.ReadAll to fail when reading body of httpresponse, without using httptest

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, httpserver

I am currently trying to avoid httpserver. Reason behind is that I am trying a different approach and write all my unit tests by mocking the httpClient, passed as interface to my logic.

The problem I am having at the moment is that I want my logic, see right below, to fail when the response cannot be read:

```
defer res.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error reading response body: %w", err)
}
```

where `res` comes from:

```
res, err := myClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Could not submit file: %w", err)
}
```

`myClient` is of an interface type that implements the `Do` method, hence I am able to mock it.
After reading some questions on the related matter I tried to mock my client's `Do` method to return:

```
response := http.Response{
    Body:          ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString("")),
    ContentLength: 1
}
```

I based myself on top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171123/how-to-force-error-on-reading-response-body/53173459#53173459) question. Unfortunately this doesn't work and my code is still able to read the body without generating an error.

Comment: bytes.NewBufferString("") never fails reading. You must provide your own type of reader (implementing io.Reader) that actually _fails_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a sample program to help you understand how to deal with this scenario. Let's see the two files involved:

#### `main.go`

```golang
package mockhttpbody

import "net/http"

func DummyServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", "1")
}
```

This file is the same one you take from the other question, so I won't cover anything here.

#### `main_test.go`

```golang
package mockhttpbody

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

type mockReader struct{}

func (m *mockReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return 0, io.ErrUnexpectedEOF
}

func Test(t *testing.T) {
    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/example", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    DummyServer(w, req)

    data, err := io.ReadAll(&mockReader{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Let's tackle this step-by-step.

##### `io` package

I suggest you use the package `io` instead of `ioutil` as the latter has been deprecated.

##### `Reader` implementation

The mock that you really need for what you want to achieve is of this interface:

```golang
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

This comes into play when you issue the `io.ReadAll` function. Here you've to pass your own custom implementation. You can define your implementation with the following code:

```golang
type mockReader struct{}

func (m *mockReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return 0, io.ErrUnexpectedEOF
}
```

Then, in your test code, you have to use this `data, err := io.ReadAll(&mockReader{})` (so the result returned from the mock HTTP server is useless).

##### `ErrUnexpectedEOF`

Last, the `io.ReadAll` function doesn't treat the `EOF` as an error so you should use something different. The error I choose is the `ErrUnexpectedEOF` one but it's up to you this decision.

Let me know if this clarifies a little bit!

Comment: this was a very clear explanation.. lesson behind is that if I want to reach what I was trying to do, I need to create an extra layer/interface on top of it, with the same method signature and mock that. thanks a lot!

Comment: You're more than welcome!